# Are there risks in using a third-party TTL cable?

Tags: lighting, ttl, cables

I see that the cables that support TTL offered by manufacturers such as Canon and Nikon for using a flash off-camera are fairly spendy and that there are some third-party cables at a fraction of the price.

What does one risk/lose in using a third party cable as opposed to the name-brand offerings?

Comment: I think this question would apply to _any_ camera-vendor-branded TTL cables, not just Canon and Nikon.

Comment: I suppose that's true.  I'll update my wording.

Comment: A related question: If you are using a name-brand cable, does the camera know that your flash is off-camera, or does it work exactly as if it was on-camera?

Comment: @Jukka: Cameras don't know or care if their flash is off camera or not. They do their metering the same way, so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the fragility of the worst of the knock-offs (which are likely to carry name-brand markings at a way-too-good-to-be-a-white-lie prices), my worry would be adequate shielding and twisting together of the appropriate wire pairs/triplets. That would show up as a smearing of the signals (you'd need an oscilloscope to actually see it).

In functional terms, it could affect the WWT* signal on very short duration flashes (for *really* close work, near the flash's minimum rated range) and possibly the chatty control signals that go on during high-speed sync. At close ranges it could significantly overexpose; at longer ranges the extra microseconds won't make nearly as much of a difference. You can test HSS fairly easily -- if it doesn't work at high shutter speeds, you may still have a perfectly adequate cable for X-sync or longer.

If the cable is at all well-made, it should have no problem, but if it's more than a couple of feet long and is just a bunch of straight wires in a jacket, it *might* show high-speed signalling problems. If things are really, really bad, your neighbor's garage door might open every time you take a picture -- and if that happens, it's worth hanging onto the cable just for that.

*WWT is a TLA for the French Canadian exclamation, "whoa, whoa tabernac!" It's a common name for the shut-off signal in any piece of Canadian military electronics -- talking about the "WWT strobe voltage transient" is much more impressive to passers-by than talking about the off switch signal.

Comment: I liked the bit about the garage door